# Classification of the Singularities of the function

Tags: complex-analysis

The only singularities I can see in the function $$\frac{1}{1+z^3}$$ is the simple pole at $-1,\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2},\frac{1-i\sqrt3}{2}$. Am I right ?

What about the singularities of the function $$\frac{1}{\sin z}$$

Comment: Yes, there are three simple poles, given by the roots of $z^3+1=0$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as user_of_math pointed out, the zeros are of order one, and are located at the 3 primitive roots os unity.

In Mathematica:

```
Solve[1 + z^3 == 0, z]
```

which gives

```
{{z -> -1}, {z -> (-1)^(1/3)}, {z -> -(-1)^(2/3)}}
```